# How to specify number of logs after each match of a particular string using docker log?

Tags: docker, docker-logs

I am new to using docker-log commands. I understood how to print logs that match specific string using **grep command**, here is a simple example:

```
docker logs {dockerId} | grep "someString"
```

However, my goal is to per each match print the next specific number of logs.

How can I achieve this using docker log commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the argument `-A <n>` in `grep` to print out `<n>` lines after the matched line

```
docker logs {dockerId} | grep "someString" -A <number of logs>
```